# Should just tag edits to questions be rejected?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

Just wondering what the procedure is around question edits that are simply tag changes. Now, assuming that in an example case the tags added are correct, is this enough alone to warrant an edit?

I ask because I see them a lot when reviewing the edit queue, but usually find myself rejecting them as *too minor*

Comment: I do kinda feel like this is a duplicate; if you care to provide examples of the edits you're concerned about, that might help differentiate it.

Comment: @Shog9: Since I am much more active at Ask Ubuntu, I would provide you the examples from there - we use version specific tags (12.04, 12.10, etc.) only if it deals with hardware-specific issue or something which is relevant only for a particular version of Ubuntu. However, quite a few questions only contain version specific tags and not the actual relevant tags which explain the main crux of the problem. Editing tags in such cases is actually a very good edit. This is one such example situation.

Comment: @Shog9: See the first revision of these two questions to give you some examples: [Example 1](http://askubuntu.com/q/265386/114818) and [Example 2](http://askubuntu.com/q/265347/114818). These are just 2 questions which were posted recently with only version specific tags, we come across many such questions everyday. Moreover, this is just one example situation - there are other cases too, when a good (more relevant) tag is not used by the OP and we edit them :-)

Comment: Hi @Shog9.. I don't mind if your reply is still a "NO". But I would appreciate some inputs from you - whatever random thoughts you have about it - it would help me enhance my understanding. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tag edits are fine. That is, if the question has no other flaws which need fixing, and the tags actually help to clarify/categorize the question.

If the edit fits those criteria, I usually don't reject them.

Answer (score 7):

I usually filter questions so that I see those tagged `C++` but no those tagged `C`. So tag change may result in me seeing or not seeing the question. I don't think it's minor.
Moreover the same question tagged as `C++` may receive totally different answers than when tagged as `C`.

Answer (score 5):

Tags form an integral part of this Q&A Network (and the whole web in general). Editing tags to insert relevant tags or removing unnecessary tags is actually a very good edit. It cannot be considered as minor. Editing tags IMO is much better than just fixing one/two typos.

People generally filter the questions through tags and try to look out for questions that they might want to answer. A lot of people only look at particular tags and don't go through all the questions which get posted on the site. For example, on Ask Ubuntu, people from Canonical are subscribed to tags like [[tag:mobile]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mobile), [[tag:ubuntu-touch]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-touch), [[tag:ubuntu-one]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-one), etc. They look at the questions tagged as such and try to provide answers for them.

Similarly, I for example, on Stack Overflow only look at questions tagged as [python](/questions/tagged/python). So, if a good question which is relevant for python users is missing this tag, I would not be able to come across that question.

So, don't just reject tag edits as minor. Instead look if the edit is correct!!!