# Tags not understood by reviewers?

Tags: discussion, tags, review, suggested-edits

On some posts I have noticed that the wrong tags have been used. e.g. `routing` instead of `url-routing`.... The former applies to network routing and it totally separate from the latter.

However, if I've edited these tags as a suggestion sometimes they have been rejected with the reason `This edit is too minor; suggested edits should be substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post` and this has sometimes caused it to fail the group vote and the edit was rejected.

To me this is more than minor for the edit to be rejected and this answer supports this: [Should just tag edits to questions be rejected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170388/should-just-tag-edits-to-questions-be-rejected)

I guess this could be because the reviewer doesn't understand the differences in the meanings of the tags. Is this an education issue for both the OP and the reviewer... should the site somehow make the tag descriptions more prominent so they are more likely to be read? Or could there be some sort of `did you mean?` prompt for tags of similar names but in different categories (if such categories exist)?

Comment: Did you address *other* problems in the post? Don't just edit tags, fix grammar and spelling mistakes too, remove 'Thank you', fix formatting, etc. too.

Comment: Looking over your edit suggestions you generally do make great edit suggestions; however, in [this suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3448510) you missed the 'Thanks' signature, you could have removed that.

Answer (score 8):

Don't just go round finding posts that are incorrectly tagged. Your suggested edits require time to review, don't waste reviewer time by *just* retagging and ignoring other problems with the post.

[This suggested edit of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3448510) was justifiably rejected, because there were *other* issues with that post you should have addressed. That post ends with:

> Thanks, da5id

which you could have removed. You probably missed this because you were focussing solely on finding mistagged posts.

Other suggested edits you've made are excellent, try to keep up that standard. :-)

Comment: So edits should really be all or nothing? Even though the post is improved, unless there were enough edits to make it worthwhile the original one is better. I understand, as it will make the question appear "fresh" again.

Comment: They should be *substantial*; reviewers won't nitpick if you missed a misspelled word, but you should make an effort to address multiple problems if there is more than one thing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

If the tag is completely wrong and you couldn't find anything else wrong with the post other than that (if there is and you ignored it that would justify a reject as Martijn pointed out), just make it clear in the edit comment.

Don't just write `Fixed tags` as you did, explain why they're completely wrong in a few words. I always try to take into account the comment attached with the edit. Of course, if the edit is substantial enough you could do without it, but it's always good to explain - some reviewers may even learn something from it :)